# Displaying Static Tooltips in v1.31

Tags: google-visualization

The most recent update of the Google Visualization API has the following in the release notes:

> Now possible to show persistent values next to bars, columns, points, etc.

I assume this means you can have labels on the charts (finally!) without any interaction.

How do you actually do it? There is nothing in the documentation yet. I checked [the google group page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-visualization-api) but didn't see any examples or pointers on how to do it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The release notes are referring to support for annotations for BarCharts and ColumnCharts (and a handful of other charts that did not support them previously).  Here's an example:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});

    data.addRows([
        ['Foo', 53, 'Foo text'],
        ['Bar', 71, 'Bar text'],
        ['Baz', 36, 'Baz text'],
        ['Cad', 42, 'Cad text'],
        ['Qud', 87, 'Qud text'],
        ['Pif', 64, 'Pif text']
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, {
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        vAxis: {
            maxValue: 100
        }
    });
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/LrGp3/

Comment: Definitely not the right answer, but led me to the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [asgallant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20278425/1933347) I figured it out.

Using his code as a base, I changed the package from 1 to 1.31.

With `google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', callback: drawChart});` this is what you get:

[image: old]

With `google.load('visualization', '1.31', {packages: ['corechart', callback: drawChart});` this is what you get:

[image: new]

I assume there are probably other methods to move the annotations outside the bars or the like, but we'll have to wait for updated documentation.

<sup>Note: asgallant's code is missing the `c` in `corechart` so it won't render as-is</sup>

Comment: D'oh!  You're right, missing the "c" (also missing the closing "]"), fixed now.  You don't need to specify v1.31, though.  Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/LrGp3/