# How to Add Data Labels in Google Chart

Tags: google-visualization, google-sheets

I have created a bar chart using google spreadsheet.  I just want to ask how I can put data labels (just like in Excel) to show the value of each bar.  Is there a way to do that without using a script?  Thank you

Comment: You can get labels on the bars by using an `'annotation'` role column, but that requires writing custom javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying Static Tooltips in v1.31](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256593/displaying-static-tooltips-in-v1-31)

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the chart itself, or during creation of the chart, you will be greeted with the "Chart Editor" window.  In the top of the window there will be three tabs, from left to right: Recommendations, Chart Type, Customization.  Under the **Customization Tab** if you scroll down to the very bottom, in between the "Point Shape" drop down menu and the "Error Bars" drop down menu, there is a drop down menu named "**Data Labels**" simple change the default of "none" to "Value" and wha-la labels.

To get labels for both X and Y coordinates simply scroll up to the **"Axis" drop down menu** (this is still under the customization tab) and switch the Axis from Horizontal to Vertical, or vise versa and repeat the above steps.